# Hiring and buying used bicycle in Tbilisi, Georgia

Tags: georgia-country, bicycles

Are there any bike rental possibilities in Tbilisi and surroundings? What are the rules and prices?
Is it possible to buy an used bicycle, I mean something cheap that just is able to move for a week? How much could a bike like that cost?

Comment: As a side note, I've been to Tbilisi numerous times, the last time only about a month ago - and there are _very_ few bicycles in the city.  I think it's just not a safe method of transport.  Once you go out of Tbilisi, to smaller towns, there, yes, I've seen a lot of bicycles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, it's possible.

Firstly, bike rental, either as part of a tour or on your own can be done from companies like [Georiders](http://www.georidersmtb.com/):

> Georiders offers mountain bike and bicycle tours in and around the
>   Caucasus mountains, custom made tours for individuals and groups and
>   bicycle rental in Tbilisi.

As for buying a bike, there are mixed comments online, but [this thread on Lonely Planet about buying one](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/europe-eastern-europe-the-caucasus/topics/bicycle-shop-in-tbilisi) - a few posts down show some possibilities:

> Bicycle Shop in Tbilisi, Georgia is in Vake district, on Abuladze
>   str.30

and

> I found five shops in a row. See the following link for a map. It's
>   not a fancy place, but if you're looking for repair, or a used bike,
>   probably the right place to go. See this picture to get a sense of
>   what you're in for.
>
> If you're looking for a new mountain bike, you might check out xtreme
>   shop, which has two locations in Tbilisi. Their website is
>   http://xtreme.ge/.

Finally, there's this Facebook page: [Bike Rental & Bike Share places in Tbilisi, Georgia](https://www.facebook.com/search/106065422766757/places-in/433034116710064/places/intersect/).

Comment: I'm not there anymore, I can't confirm the information, but it seems to be a good answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that there are not that many bicycles in the center of Tbilisi, but at the outskirts cycling is quite popular. There are some good spots for cycling too. Once I even saw a critical mass ride in the center.

Some bicycle shops I know:
http://bicycle.ge/lang/2
https://www.facebook.com/bikehousegeo/

Hope this helps

Comment: I couldn't add more than 2 links in my answer, so here I put the rentals I know:
Rentals (some of them also offer tours)
- already mentioned Mogzauri
- https://www.georiders.ge/
- http://laklaktours.com/rental/